# Distribution of measurements given the underlying physical process distribution and the measurement uncertainty distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, convolution, sampling, error-propagation

How to express the distribution of measurements ($X_m \sim \mathcal{D}_\mathrm{unknown}$) given that the underlying physical process being measured follows a Gaussian distribution ($X_p \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_p, \sigma_p)$) and the measurement uncertainty follows a Gaussian distribution ($\mathcal{N}(\mu_u, \sigma_u)$) too?

Note: $\mu_u$ here is variable and takes the value of the specific instance/sample $X_p$.

**Update:**

Can one start in terms of PDFs as follows?

Given the PDF of the physical process:
$$f_{X_p}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma_p\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu_p}{\sigma_p}\right)^2}$$

In order to express the PDF of the measurements affected by measurement error ($\mathcal{N}(X_p, \sigma_u)$), the idea is to use an specific sample $t$ of the physical process as the mean of the measurement uncertainty distribution. Since the specific sample $t$ follows a PDF $f_{X_p}(t)$, therefore integration is used over the whole range of $t$, and weighted by the PDF:
$$f_{X_m}(x) =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma_u\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-t}{\sigma_u}\right)^2}f_{X_p}(t)dt$$

Is the above formulation reasonable?

**Update after David K's answer:**
This question can also serve to get a more intuitive understanding of the convolution of two normal distributions.

Comment: I thought measurement error was usually considered to have a distribution like $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_u)$, that is, it's something added to the actual value in a way that introduces uncertainty but not bias. Is there a reason to formulate it differently?

Comment: The idea here is to figure out a way to express the measurements of the noise-like physical process including the measurement uncertainty. Basically, the question is how the distribution of the noisy measurements of the noise-like physical process look like? Which I think is different than adding the two distributions, do you agree?

Comment: I agree up to the point where you say it is different from adding two distributions. I think it is the same, unless you have some reason to believe that larger actual values of a particular output of the process tend to result in larger (or smaller) errors of measurement of that output. Then you need to say what the dependency is. (It's still a sum of two variables but the joint distribution is more complicated then.)

Comment: I just realized you're writing "measurement uncertainty" where I would have written "measurement error." _Uncertainty of measurement_ is a single parameter, such as a standard deviation: https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Uncertainty/glossary.html

Comment: If you have a source for your definitions I think you should cite it in the question.

Comment: About the error dependence on the actual process values, this is the not the assumption here. Measurement error has the same standard deviation $\sigma_p$ throughout. I empirically can reproduce what you are saying, by a MATLAB script, I see that you are right. But I can't seem to intuitively understand that the expression that I added in the question has the same affect as adding two random variables following Gaussian distributions. Or may be my formulation (in the question update) is flawed.

Comment: I was under the impression that uncertainty or error can be used interchangeably here in the context of propagation of error/uncertainty (see also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty)

Comment: In math jargon, the meaning of "foo bar" is not the meaning of foo plus the meaning of bar. An article on the "propagation of ____" is not going to tell you what the word in the blank means when it stands on its own. However, notice that what gets propagated are variances and covariances. But in the end, despite those quibbles about semantics, I think you formulated the problem correctly in your edit of the question. I expanded on this further in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step back a little and consider the mathematics, not the application.

Suppose we have a random variable $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$
and another random variable  $X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_2)$.
That is, we have two general Gaussian distributions, except that the second distribution has mean zero.

The density function of $X_1$ is
$$
f_{X_1}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-((x-\mu_1)/\sigma_1)^2/2}.
$$

The density function of $X_2$ is
$$
f_{X_2}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma_2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x/\sigma_2)^2/2}.
$$

The density function of the sum $X_1 + X_2$ is the convolution of the two individual density functions, which can be computed in several equivalent ways, one of which is

\begin{align}
f_{X_1+X_2}(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_2}(x - t)f_{X_1}(t)\,dt \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma_2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-((x - t)/\sigma_2)^2/2}
       f_{X_1}(t)\,dt.
\end{align}

This equation should look familiar, because the right-hand side on the last line is the integral you developed for $f_{X_m}(x)$, provided that $X_1 = X_p$ and $\sigma_2 = \sigma_u.$

In other words, the $X_m$ you are trying to describe is simply
$X_p + X_u,$ where $X_u \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_u)$.

The variable $X_u$ is what I would consider the error, which has mean zero.
It is the difference between the measurement and the actual value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This exercise unintentionally helped me get a more intuitive understanding of the convolution of distributions. :)